# Declaring variable in splitted string in c# and search the db row between those strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have an requirement like search functionality,
Edit: Search is like set of varchars usually this ID contains values like C001,C002,...

so if user is entering the ranges like C001-C010 it should search all the rows in oracle db in between that C001-C010 this is what my requirement.

If user is entering some ranges like C001-C010 in text box this should be splited as two variables and it should search all the elements in between this range.

How to do this. I think using Enumerator range we can do this but i am facing problem like splitting strings needs to declared as separate variable and search between that. which I cant achieve.

sample code is below.

```
            else if (!_search.MultipleId.Contains('-'))
            {
                filterExp = filterExp.And(x => x.Id.Contains(_search.MultipleId));
            }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. To split the string you would simply `var searchstrings = _search.MutlipleId.Split('-')` but what are you intending to search with the values in the resultant array is not defined. Please clarify your question.

Comment: To add to what @crunchy said, we also need to understand the field you're searching. The answers I see currently take the approach of generating a set of possible strings and searching for them; however, if the search field can be searched as an integer, using the range to produce a greater than/lesser than search would be much more efficient.

Comment: Hi @crunchy Edited the question properly could you please check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static HashSet<string> getIdsFromRangeQuery(string multipleIds)
{
multipleIds = multipleIds.ToUpper().Replace(" ", "");

HashSet<string> inSet = new HashSet<string>();

string[] parts = multipleIds.Split(new[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string part in parts)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^M([0 - 9] +)C([0 - 9] +)$");
    Regex rgxTwo = new Regex(@"^M([0-9]+)C([0-9]+)-M([0-9]+)C([0-9]+)$");
    Regex rgxThree = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$");
    Regex rgxFour = new Regex(@"^([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)$");
    if (rgx.IsMatch(part))
    {
        inSet.Add(part);
    }
    else if (rgxTwo.IsMatch(part))
    {
        string[] fromTo = part.Split(new[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        int mFrom = int.Parse(fromTo[0].Substring(1, fromTo[0].IndexOf("C")));
        int mTo = int.Parse(fromTo[1].Substring(1, fromTo[1].IndexOf("C")));

        int cFrom = int.Parse(fromTo[0].Substring(fromTo[0].LastIndexOf("C") + 1));
        int cTo = int.Parse(fromTo[1].Substring(fromTo[1].LastIndexOf("C") + 1));

        for (int i = mFrom; i <= mTo; i++)
        {
            for (int j = cFrom; j <= cTo; j++)
            {
                inSet.Add("M" + i + "C" + j);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (rgxThree.IsMatch(part))
    {
        inSet.Add(part);
    }
    else if (rgxFour.IsMatch(part)
    {
        string[] fromTo = part.Split(new[] { "-" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        int from = int.Parse(fromTo[0]);
        int to = int.Parse(fromTo[1]);
        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++)
        {
            inSet.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        inSet.Add(part);
    }
}

return inSet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help:

```
var pair = yourstring.Split('-')
        .Select(a => new { one= a[0], two= a[1]});
```

Comment: That will split at the `-` position, create 2 columns `one` and `two`, but it will also create multiple rows containing the 1st, 2nd, 3rd ... character in the columns, which is not quite what was asked. And btw. there is one extra closing bracket `)`that you need to remove.

Answer (score 1):

If the Id is in format of CXXX then you can do something like this:

```
    if(_search.MultipleId.Contain("-"))
{
var range = _search.MultipleId.Split('-');
filterExp = filterExp.And(x => x.Id >= range[0] && x.Id <= range1);
}
```

Comment: Here Id is string so I cant use logical operators. Sorry for the question which was not clear now i edited the same can you please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing all of you business requirements, you could try something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new List<string> { "C001", "C010" };
        var firstChar = new List<string>();
        var remainingChars = new List<string>();

        items.ForEach(i =>
        {
            firstChar.Add(i[0].ToString());
            remainingChars.Add(i.Substring(1));
        });

        firstChar.ForEach(f => { Console.Write(f + " "); });
        Console.WriteLine();
        remainingChars.ForEach(r => { Console.Write(r + " "); });
        Console.WriteLine();

        //Prints the following
        //C C
        //001 010
        //Press any key to continue . . .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would cast the dataset to a list so I could use the indices of the start and end args.

```
        var items = dataset.ToList();

        var searchString = "B1, C10";
        var removedWhitespace = Regex.Replace(searchString, @"\s+", "");

       var rangeToSearch = removedWhitespace.Split(',');

        var startPosition = items.FindIndex(x => x.ID == rangeToSearch.First());
        var endPosition = items.FindIndex(x => x.ID == rangeToSearch.Last());

        var selectedItems =
            items.Skip(startPosition).Take(endPosition - startPosition + 1); // +1 to include the original id's
```

If you have to you can order the list, but one caveat with this method is that the list is ordered alphabetically, so you may have to do some additional processing to make sure that you return all the values in the range.

Comment: Almost this was the correct idea but to  be perfect some modifications needed as you suggested.